# Referencing reusable forms (2 deep) in MS Access

Tags: class, vba, ms-access

I have multiple Members, and each one has a record which contains several memo fields:

```
Member ID    Entry A       Entry B
   1        [memo text]   [memo text]
   2        [memo text]   [memo text]
   3        [memo text]   [memo text]
```

In Access 2007, I am creating a Memo Entry form that is the equivalent of `Shift-F2` -- A dedicated window to review and edit the content.  Unlike `Shift-F2`, this must be reusable.

I must mention that the form for showing details about a Member is also reusable.  Following the plan above (which is abbreviated), I could have up to three Member forms and six Memo Entry forms open at once.

The solution below works well EXCEPT that the critical event `UpdateComment()` is only triggered once per Member-form instead of once per Memo-form.  So if I open **A** and **B** for the same member and make edits, only one edit will be passed to the calling form.

Somehow I am failing to provide the calling form, `Member Detail`, with a method to treat the Memo forms as unique.  How do I solve that?

#### Member Detail form -- this does the spawning

```vb
Dim strFieldName As String, varValue
Private WithEvents frmZoom As Form_frmMemberInputZoom

Private Sub btnView_A_Click()
    strFieldName = "boxQuality_A"
    varValue = Me(strFieldName)
    Call OpenMemberInput(Me!boxID, strFieldName, varValue, True)
End Sub

Private Sub btnView_B_Click()
    strFieldName = "boxQuality_B"
    varValue = Me(strFieldName)
    Call OpenMemberInput(Me!boxID, strFieldName, varValue, True)
End Sub

Private Sub frmZoom_UpdateComment(lngID As Long, _ 
                    strAssessStage As String, varReturn)

    Dim intCount As Integer
    For intCount = 1 To collectnZooms.Count
        If collectnZooms(intCount)![boxID] = lngID _
           And collectnZooms(intCount)![boxAssessStage] = strAssessStage _ 
              Then

                Me(strAssessStage) = varReturn
                Me.Dirty = False

                Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Close()
    Dim obj As Object

    For Each obj In collectnMembers
        If obj.Hwnd = Me.Hwnd Then
            collectnMembers.Remove CStr(Me.Hwnd)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub OpenMemberInput(lngID As Long, strStage As String, _
                    varComment, booEdit As Boolean)

    Set frmZoom = New Form_frmMemberInputZoom

    frmZoom.Caption = CStr(frmZoom.Hwnd)

    frmZoom.ID = lngID 
    frmZoom.Stage = strStage
    frmZoom.ProviderName = "Dr " & CStr(lngID)
    frmZoom.Comment = varComment

    frmZoom.Visible = True

    collectnZooms.Add Item:=frmZoom, Key:=CStr(frmZoom.Hwnd)

End Sub
```

#### Memo Entry form -- this one is spawned

```
Public Event UpdateComment(lngID As Long, strAssessStage As String, _ 
                           varReturn)

Private lngAssess_ID As Long
Private strAssessStage As String
Private strProviderName As String
Private varComment

Public Property Let ID(ByVal MyAssessID As Long)
    lngAssess_ID = MyAssessID
    Me.boxID = lngAssess_ID
End Property

Public Property Let Stage(ByVal MyAssessStage As String)
    strAssessStage = MyAssessStage
    Me.boxAssessStage = strAssessStage
End Property

Public Property Let ProviderName(ByVal MyProviderName As String)
    strProviderName = MyProviderName
    Me.boxProviderName = strProviderName
End Property

Public Property Let Comment(ByVal varExisting)
    varComment = varExisting
    Me.boxComment = varComment
End Property

Public Property Get Comment()
    Comment = varComment
End Property

Private Sub boxComment_AfterUpdate()
    varComment = Me.boxComment
    Comment = varComment
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Close()

    '#################################################################
    ' Line below will be called for only ONE of the multiple instances
    '#################################################################

    RaiseEvent UpdateComment(lngAssess_ID, strAssessStage, varComment)

    Dim obj As Object
    For Each obj In collectnZooms
        If obj.Hwnd = Me.Hwnd Then
            collectnZooms.Remove CStr(Me.Hwnd)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I also found that it always goes with the last form opened.

Comment: Why don't you call a public sub on the parent form instead of using the raise event route?

Comment: I could have tried that.  It didn't occur to me because I am so accustomed to opting for a standard module.  I would like to point out, though, that the use of multiple instances of the parent form could make your suggestion difficult to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As recommended in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3731712/122139):

- Dismantle the `RaiseEvent` function.
- Use `.Visible` to avoid closing out the Memo Entry form (which throws things off).

#### Member Detail form -- this does the spawning

```vb
Dim strFieldName As String, varValue
'Private WithEvents ... NAH, WE WON'T GO THERE  

Private Sub btnView_A_Click()
    strFieldName = "boxQuality_A"
    varValue = Me(strFieldName)
    Call OpenMemberInput(Me!boxID, strFieldName, varValue, True)
End Sub

Private Sub btnView_B_Click()
    strFieldName = "boxQuality_B"
    varValue = Me(strFieldName)
    Call OpenMemberInput(Me!boxID, strFieldName, varValue, True)
End Sub

'Private Sub frmZoom_UpdateComment(lngID As Long, strAssessStage As String, varReturn)
'    ... NAH, we won't be using this...
'End Sub

Private Sub Form_Close()

    Dim obj As ObjecT
    For Each obj In collectnMembers
        If obj.Hwnd = Me.Hwnd Then
            collectnMembers.Remove CStr(Me.Hwnd)
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Sub OpenMemberInput(lngID As Long, strStage As String, _
                    varComment, booEdit As Boolean)

    Dim FoundMe As Boolean
    FoundMe = v_MemberComment.FetchForm(lngID, strStage)
    If FoundMe Then Exit Sub

    Dim frmZoom As New Form_frmMemberInputZoom

    Set frmZoom = New Form_frmMemberInputZoom


    frmZoom.ID = lngID 
    frmZoom.Stage = strStage
    frmZoom.Comment = varComment

    frmZoom.Visible = True

    collectnZooms.Add Item:=frmZoom, Key:=CStr(frmZoom.Hwnd)

End Sub
```

#### Memo Entry form -- this one is spawned

```
'' NAH, no use of the Public Event
'Public Event UpdateComment(lngID As Long, strAssessStage As String, varReturn)

Private lngAssess_ID As Long
Private strAssessStage As String
Private varComment

Public Property Let ID(ByVal MyAssessID As Long)
    lngAssess_ID = MyAssessID
    Me.boxID = lngAssess_ID
End Property

Public Property Let Stage(ByVal MyAssessStage As String)
    strAssessStage = MyAssessStage
    Me.boxAssessStage = strAssessStage
End Property

Public Property Let Comment(ByVal varExisting)
    varComment = varExisting
    Me.boxComment = varComment
End Property

Public Property Get Comment()
    Comment = varComment
End Property

Private Sub boxComment_AfterUpdate()
    varComment = Me.boxComment
    Comment = varComment
End Sub

Private Sub CmdCancel_Click()
    ''TODO revert to before-update text if Cancel is selected
    Me.Tag = "Cancel"
    Me.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub CmdOK_Click()

    Dim intCount As Integer, frm As Form, lngHwnd As Long
    For intCount = 1 To collectnMembers.Count

        Set frm = collectnMembers(intCount)
        If frm![boxID] = lngAssess_ID Then
                frm(strAssessStage) = varComment
                frm.Requery
        End If
    Next

    Me.Visible = False

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Close()

    'RaiseEvent .... NAH, DON'T BOTHER

    Dim obj As Object
    For Each obj In collectnZooms
        If obj.Hwnd = Me.Hwnd Then
            collectnZooms.Remove CStr(Me.Hwnd)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

#### VBA Standard Module to support above form

```vb
Public collectnZooms As New Collection

Public Function FetchForm(lngID As Long, strStage As String) As Boolean

    Dim intCount As Integer
    For intCount = 1 To collectnZooms.Count

        If collectnZooms(intCount)![boxID] = lngID _
           And collectnZooms(intCount)![boxAssessStage] = strStage Then
                FetchForm = True
                collectnZooms(intCount).Tag = ""

                collectnZooms(intCount).Visible = True

                Exit Function
        End If

    Next
End Function
```