# Use Z-order and position to organize open forms in MS Access

Tags: forms, vba, winapi, ms-access

For MS Access 2010, I need a way to flexibly maintain the position and Z-order when a dozen forms are open.  There can be multiple instances of the Parent form, and each one can lead to multiple instances of the Child form (some [background here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22108012/122139)).

I want the user to be able to choose which form is top-most -- which means I don't want any forms set as `Popup`.  Also, I want the Z-Order essentially preserved when a new Child opens.  As the Child opens, the Parent loses the focus; at that point I'd like the Parent to drop back to its former position in the Z-order.  I could add requirements along this line, but you get the idea ... I imagined a default behavior might do what I want, but if I have to assign Z-order locations from an array or something like that, I could accept that.

I also want to control the on-screen position of the Child forms (I mean only when they are first opened; they can be repositioned).  If they open with the same `X,Y` coordinates, they'll appear stacked on top of each other and the user will have to reposition the top instance in order to see the others.  That is inconvenient and, more important I think, disorienting.

So far I'm not able to have it all.  I can get a nice cascade result by specifying `X,Y` positions, but it stops working when I use the flags to poke at the Z-order.

I've been using the API...

```
Declare Sub SetWindowPos Lib "user32" ( _
                ByVal Hwnd&, _
                ByVal hWndInsertAfter&, _
                ByVal X&, ByVal Y&, ByVal cX&, _
                ByVal cY&, ByVal wFlags&)

Global Const HWND_TOP = 0
Global Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1

SetWindowPos Hwnd, HWND_TOP, lngPosX, lngPosX, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE
```

I have different results when I try options for `hWndInsertAfter&` and `wFlags&`.  Also when I set forms as `Popup` (results are better, but as mentioned, I want the user to bring any form to the top; therefore no `Popup`).

(Hmm... I bet `Popup` (and 'Modal`) are precisely what bring the API into best usage, because while a "must-answer" dialog is showing, control basically reverts to Windows.  Confirm?)

My biggest frustration is that documentation for the API seems fragmentary and incoherent.  And I wonder, *am I stuck with that API?  Is there something else I can use?*  I'd love a VBA solution apart from the API, but I guess this is what the API is for.  Still, is there a method I'm missing?

I can post my variant attempts in more detail, but I feel I've been shooting in the dark, so I will wait on your feedback.

### Update

I tried Reading [The Manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  I tried twiddling with "form ownership" and `NO/TOPMOST`.  For the Child form, **I still have to choose between:**

1. Being able to set the position upon opening
2. Being able to bring the Parent form back "on top" of the Child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the solution doesn't exist, or isn't worth pursuing because it would lean on Windows API libraries that may not be available in a few years.  (This pessimism is not based on specific insights; but in general I see big pressures on the Windows user interface, so it's easy to imagine things shifting.)

I see some other hazards.  Users will open numerous windows; resources will fail at some point, and probably before then they'll have lost any advantages from a human analytical point of view.  Nonetheless they'll continue past the point of diminishing returns.  Also I can expect to find a few pitfalls that gobble development time and lead in the end to complaints no matter how much time I spend mitigating them.  Think "multi-user" and you'll know what I mean.

Instead, I need to re-think the approach.  The application offers complicated and sometimes volumnous information.  There's a way to do it.  Not this way.

I might delete this OP, but it's gotten three up-votes, so I'll wait and see what you think.  I can always punt to community wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer! I bumped into this while searching for a related issue.

One way to manage Z-order 'Access-only' is to use Form.SetFocus. The general solution outline:

1. Keep an array or collection of your form names and their Z-orders
2. When Z-order changes:
3. Resort your list to reflect the new Z-order
4. Turn screen updating off: Application.Echo False
5. Iterate through your list of forms in reverse Z-order. Use Form.SetFocus for each form. This will put the highest form on top.
6. Turn screen updating back on: Application.Echo True

This should work as long as all of your forms are non-modal.

If you need modal forms, be aware that they are by default on top, and you can only have one modal form open at a time. You can still use the above logic, just be sure to set Form.Modal = False for every form not on the top.

This is the 'how' answer, but I can't offer advice as to whether this is a sound approach for your application.