# access 2003 on windows 10 - RaiseEvent seems not to work

Tags: vba, ms-access

A very simple mdb: form1 has just a button Command0, form2 has just a button Command0.

- The button on form1 loads form2.
- The button on form2 raises event "doit".
- This event never gets triggered.

Why?
This is all the code there is in the form:

FORM1

```
Option Compare Database
Private WithEvents msg As Form
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "form2"
    Set msg = Forms("form2")
End Sub
Sub msg_doit()
    Stop
End Sub
```

FORM2

```
Option Compare Database
Public Event doit()

Private Sub Command0_Click()
    RaiseEvent doit
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event not Firing in MS Access VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730883/event-not-firing-in-ms-access-vba)

Comment: I've never seen RaiseEvent used in VBA. https://www.engram9.info/visual-basic-vba/raiseevent-statement.html What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @June7 That's a different issue (events don't work with dialog-type forms because they interrupt other running code). Events are not that uncommon, and are useful if you want multiple different pieces of code to be able to detect an action on a form (or any other action). I don't use them much, but for large applications they can certainly be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the proper (specific) interface that contains your event.

For forms, the `Access.Form` interface is the general one (for all forms) and only contains the built-in methods and events, the `Access.Form_MyFormName` is the specific interface that contains all public methods and events you declared as well.

The only thing you need to change is:

```
Private WithEvents msg As Form_form2
```

Then it should just work.